# MongoDb: Best way to store time range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to store something like `startTime` and `endTime` in my document. To give some more context, these will reflect the opening and closing times for a shop. So, for example, `startTime` could be 9AM and `endTime` could be 9PM. What is the best way to store this? This is what I am doing right now:

```
timings: {
    startTime: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "....."]
    },
    endTime: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "....."]
    }
  }
```

The idea is to store the values as strings ("9AM", "9PM") and do some sort of time parsing each time I query the database. But I was wondering if there was a better approach to this? Another idea I had is to store it as `DateTime` and ignore the date part. What else can I do? I'd like to avoid parsing/processing on application level as much as possible and leverage the power of mongodb.

I'm using mongoose and nodeJS.

Comment: Do you want to store time only or date also?

Comment: Just the times. I want to be able to store the opening and closing timings for a shop, an example would be openingTime: 9AM, closingTime: 9PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree the Date type is not relevant (and it has something to do with time zones and you might not want to get there ...)

I would store it as a number, not a string. Why ? because you might want to query it (like all "give me all shops that opens after 8pm"), and doing it with a string will be annoying ...

I'd go with that :

```
{
    startTime: {
        value: number;
        amOrPm: string; //(if you don't want to use a 24 hours base)
    },
    endTime: {
        value: number;
        amOrPm: string; //(if you don't want to use a 24 hours base)
    },

    timeOffset: number // So you keep track on the offset with the base timezone 
}
```

You could also store the minutes, or even store the time only in "minutes ellapsed since midnight" and convert it every time there is an access.

Having the offset this way won't allow you to easily query for a specific moment across different timezones, but I guess it's totally useless in your case.

Also you could store days as a number ('officially' sunday is 0, then monday is 1), but nowadays it is as easy to store a name so well ...

Edit: for the days maybe it's better to go with an array :

```
{
    daysOppenned: [0, 1, 4]
}
```

And finally, what if each day has a different time openning ? Maybe you would have to consider having an array of days, each containing the time openning and time of closing, like above.

If you want to get even more into details, some shops are closed in middays and some other (like restaurants) only opens two times a day, you could then offer them to tick cases on a schedule and store that in an array.

Let us know if you need to build somthing like that !

Comment: How would you convert this back to AM/PM format? I'm using 24 hour format to store the time (540 = 9AM, 1260 = 9PM).

Comment: You want to update your database with existing entries to am/pm format ?

Comment: No, I am trying to serve a frontend. The frontend expects me to send the timings in AM/PM format